# TopShelf application deployment using TeamCity

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services, teamcity, topshelf

I am using TopShelf to write a WinService application and I was wondering what's the standard way to deploy it using TeamCity.

Here's the scenario I came up with:

1. Agent builds the project
2. Agent copies the folder  with build results (e.g. Release) to the target machine
3. If the folder 'ServiceName' exists, Agent goes there and runs ServiceName.exe uninstall and deletes the folder
4. Agent  renames the Release folder to ServiceName.
5. Agent goes to ServiceName folder and calls ServiceName.exe install and start.

Basically, that's the way it might work. However, I am not sure if it's the most convenient one. Are there any alternatives? AFAIK, Octopus deploy might come in handy, but I am not sure. I have found good-looking articles and answers regarding a plain WinService, but not a lot about TopShelf.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity is designed for builds not deployment. I'd recommend at looking at a tool designed for deployment like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) or [FAKE.Deploy](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/deploy.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've already looked at Octopus and unfortunately we won't be able to set it up just to deploy a few services. I've come up with my own solution using PS scripts and PS remoting. Not the ideal one, though works for basic scenarios.